# How to adapt crossAxisCount of GridView based on its width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, layout, responsive-design

What is the best practice to adapt the number of columns (crossAxisCount) of a GridView based on its width in Flutter?

Maybe I can better explain the intended behaviour by referencing HTML:

- I create 6 boxes (e.g. DIVs) with a width of 200 px (and same height) each.
- (a) If the element surrounding these boxes has a width of 400 px, it would automatically show 2 boxes per row in 3 rows.
- (b) If the element surrounding these boxes has a width of 700 px, it would automatically show 3 boxes per row in 2 rows.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Wrap. It can put renderboxes as many as fit to a row, then wrap to the next row. (formerly a comment, but it looks like the answer!)

Comment: it's very nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do this like below. You can try..

```
  int getItemCountPerRow(BuildContext context) {
    double minTileWidth = 200; //in your case
    double availableWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    
    int i = availableWidth ~/ minTileWidth;
    return i;

  }
```

Comment: If I understand this solution correctly, it is a method that calculates the amount of items per row based on the screen width. So this solution would be limited to use cases, where the width of the GridView equals the width of the screen. This solution is close, but not the solution I need in my very specific use case.

Comment: yes. you need to modify according to your need. i have just shared the approach what i generally do.